# Unable to persist messages forever in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Need to understand how can I persist messages produced on kafka forever. I have set the properties `log.retention.hours= -1` and `log.retention.bytes= -1` in my `server.properties` file but still the messages get deleted in few days. Am I missing any other configuration?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It may depend on the version that you use. Try to set log.retention.hours=2147483647, this works for sure.

Comment: @KatyaGorshkova Let me try that.Also any idea how can I test this without actually waiting for few days.Would changing the system date and restarting kafka server allow me to check whether the message is retained or deleted?Or is there any other way to figure it out?

Comment: Ideally it should work for kafka v0.9+ . Are you configuring `log.dir` location as `/tmp` directory?

Comment: @NishuTayal Yes but there is no auto cleanup for /tmp directory.I can see all the directories just messages are deleted

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at log compaction for Kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

You'll need to set `log.cleanup.policy` to compact from the default of delete for this.